# Wix Patch: Starting the application or executing a CustomAction

Tags: wix, patch, process.start

I want to start the application after installing a patch (msp). With my installer (msi) the user is offered to start the application at the end of the installation.

With the patch (msp) I would like to start the application after the installation. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this as follows:

```
<Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize">PATCH</Custom>
```